# Ms-Excel - Extracting specific word from a cell and put it to another cell?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel data which contains 312 student records.
In cell B2 I have Full name of students.

[image]

**What I want to do is specifically as follows:**

- Extract first name from B2 and put it in D2
- Extract Last name from B2 and put it in E2
- Extract GFname from B2 and put it in F2
- Finnaly by dragging I want to get all rows done.

**Note: For Example the first row is done manually.**

Is there any spcial help because I'm loosing my time and effort if it is not solved.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using functions like TRIM, FIND, MID, LEFT or RIGHT